# how to show an image on django web?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I try to display the picture on web:

```html
 {% for info in chef %}
              <div class="col-md-3" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
                <img src="img/person_1.jpg" alt="Image placeholder" class="img-fluid mb-4 rounded">
                <h3 class="mb-3">{{info.name}}</h3>
                <p class="post-meta text-muted">{{info.title}}</p>
                <p class="mb-5"></p>
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the path as relative or absolute.

```
<img src="/img/person_1.jpg" alt="Image placeholder" class="img-fluid mb-4 rounded">
```

relative path will depend on how you config.

for django id save image in static folder then you have to like below

```
in template you have to do 

{% load static %}

<img src="{% static img/person_1.jpg %}" alt="Image placeholder" class="img-fluid mb-4 rounded">
```

I am assuming you have done the setting for static file in django settings file